# Cosine similarity loss cause weight values to explode

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

Suppose my data consists of images of bubbles, and the labels are histograms describing the distribution of sizes, for example:

```
0-10mm 10% 
10-20mm 30%
20-30mm 40%
30-40mm 20%
```

It is important to note that -

- All size percentages sum to 100% (or 1.0 to be more precise).
- I don't have annotated data, so i can't train an object detector and then just calculate the distribution by counting objects detected. However, i do have a feature extractor train on my data.

I implemented a simple CNN that consists of -

- Resnet50 backbone.
- Global max pooling.
- 1x1 convolution of 6 filters (6 distribution bins in labels).

After some experiments i came to the conclusion that softmax and cross entropy as loss function does not suit my problem and needs.

I thought that maybe a cosine similarity loss, with a light modification, may be a good alternative (normalization will be part of post process). This is the implementation:

```
def cosine_similarity_loss(logits, probs, weights=1.0, label_smoothing=0):

    x1_val = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(logits, tf.transpose(logits)), axis=1))
    x2_val = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(probs, tf.transpose(probs)), axis=1))
    denom = tf.multiply(x1_val, x2_val)

    num = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(logits, probs), axis=1)
    cosine_sim = tf.math.divide(num, denom)
    cosine_dist = tf.math.reduce_mean(1 - tf.square(cosine_sim))  # Cosine Distance. Reduce mean for shape compatibility.

    return cosine_dist
```

Loss is a summation of cosine distance and l2 regularization on weights. After first feed forward i got `loss: 3.1267` and after second feed forward i got `loss: 96003645440.0000`  - meaning weights exploded (`logits: [[-785595.812 -553858.625 -545579.625 -148547.875 -12845.8633 19871.1055]]` while `probs: [[0.466 0.297 0.19 0.047 0 0]]`).

What could be the reason for such rapid and extreme increase?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is cosine distance does an internal normalisation of the logits, removing the magnitude, and thus there is no gradient to propogate that opposes the values increasing. BTW `weights` is not used in your implementation.

What about just plain Euclidian distance using sigmoid instead of softmax in the last layer. Also, I would try adding another one or two dense layers (say size 512) between resnet50 and output dense layer.

Comment: why sigmoid instead of softmax? at least softmax is a "global" normalization that keeps the relation between the values in the logits.

Comment: "there is no gradient to propogate that opposes the values increasing" - could you please elaborate why *removing* the magnitude cause the weight to specifically *explode* like that?

Comment: @AlexGoft From what I’ve seen, SoftMax seems to be used for multi class problems (one positive class, all others negative) and sigmoid for multi label (more than one positive class) and continuous outputs. I think this is because SoftMax tends to push one value towards 1 and the rest to 0 but it might work in your case and I’d be interested to see how it compares.

Comment: @AlexGoft For the gradient, what I understand is that training works by looking at the difference between the predictions and actual values, then this is back propagated  through the network to calculate a gradient for each weight, and then the weight is updated in that direction. When you remove the magnitude, the logits can update and get much bigger or smaller without changing the cosine similarity, so long as their relative values stay the same, so there is nothing to stop them exploding.

Comment: Adding the l2 norm of the logits to the loss might stop this but that is just adding the magnitude back in so you might as well use Euclidean distance.